# Evaluating different methodologies for hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, ab-test, two-sample

I have a campaign, with a target and holdout group, in which the target group is encouraged to make a purchase.

I have the results from campaign - total revenue spent per member (for target & control)

I want to be able to compare the average revenue per group and conclude if there is a statistically significant difference between the two

[image]

Option 1 - Two sample t-test - to test if the two sample means are different (using green column)

Option 2 - Per test group member, subtract *'avg control group revenue per member'* (250+300+350)/3 ... test if the mean of resulting distribution (red column) is different from 0 (1 sample t-test with expected mean equal to 0)

Are both methods comparable? If not, why so?

EDIT

Target 7200
Holdout 3600

Comment: @user2974951 I don't think it's a paired t-test (I could be wrong) but members in both groups are independent of each other

Comment: Your second test seems to treat the estimate 300 from the control group as an exact value, not subject to random variation. If so, it is difficult to see the point of doing the second test. // I suppose you actually have more than 3 subjects in each group. What are the exact sample sizes in your real problem?

Comment: @BruceET I see your point ... My sample sizes are much larger Target 7200 Holdout 3600. You reckon a two sample test, accounting for the variability in both groups is a better test?

Comment: I'd do a two-sample test first. Then if significant and important differences are found, I'd look at fraction making purchaces and at amounts per purchace.

Comment: Cheers @BruceET.
If the fraction of people making purchases between the two groups is different and statistically significant... but the rev per member between the two groups isn't ... what would your strategy be to calculate incremental revenue? (if at all it is possible to calculate incremental revenue)